# How to define a type based on another type in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

So I have a component which accepts the following props: title, choices, onChange, selection

I want the type of the onChange prop to depend on the type selection prop like so:

```
MyComponentProps = {
  title: string;
  choices: Choice[];
  selection: 'one' | 'multiple';
  onChange: selection === 'one' ? someType : someOtherType
}
```

Is it possible to do something like this?

I tried:
`someType | someOtherType` but this is not dependent on the the `selection` prop's type.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can define two different types and then OR them in this case though.

```js
type OneProps = {
  title: string;
  choices: Choice[];
  selection: 'one';
  onChange: someType;

type MultipleProps = {
  title: string;
  choices: Choice[];
  selection: 'multiple';
  onChange: someOtherType;
}

type MyComponentProps = OneProps | MultipleProps;
```

Comment: Just a tip for OP; if you have more variants you probably don't want to duplicate `title` and `choices` if they are *always* present in `MyComponentProps`. You can use the intersection operator like `type MyComponentProps = AlwaysProps & (VariantOne | VariantTwo | VariantThree)`